# Add string value to array if its value is true

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have:

```
const apple = true
const pear = false
const coconut = true
```

I would like to have:

```
const activeFruits = ['apple', 'coconut']
```

How can I do something like this?
This is what I've tried:

```
const activeFruits = [
 apple ? 'apple' : '',
 pear ? 'pear' : '',
 coconut ? 'coconut' : '',
]
```

Then I have to filter out the empty string.

It works but doesn't seem to be to me the smartest way.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea to have a dynamic way will be to have an object that contains your variables:

```js
const fruits = {
  apple: true,
  pear: false,
  coconut: true
};

const activeFruit = Object.keys(fruits).filter(key => !!fruits[key]);

console.log(activeFruit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is smarter or the smartest, but this is a different approach

You could wrap all of the fruits into an object, transform that object into key-value pairs (using `Object.entries()`), `filter` pairs which have value of `true`, and then `map` the pairs to get the keys

```js
const apple = true
const pear = false
const coconut = true

const obj = {
  apple,
  pear,
  coconut
}

const activeFruits = Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(([_, value]) => value === true)
  .map(([key, _]) => key)

console.log(activeFruits)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I would do it like this:

```
if (apple) {
    activeFruits.push('apple');
}

if (pear) {
    activeFruits.push('pear');
}

if (coconut) {
    activeFruits.push('coconut');
}
```

However, I would question the initial data structure you have and (if possible) change it to:

```
const fruits = {
    apple: true,
    pear: false,
    coconut: true
};
```

Then get the answer like this:

```
const activeFruits = Object.keys(fruits).filter(key => !!fruits[key]);
```